# Login user with email password via REST API with Azure AD and MSAL

Tags: node.js, rest, azure-ad-msal, msal

I have a scenario where I have a react native app and a nodejs server. I need to authenticate users with Azure AD. I first thought of social auth using auth providers like Clerk, Appwrite, Supabase, Firebase, etc, but decided to instead do this: user enters their email and password and it will be sent to the backend nodejs api. This API will then use MSAL (or something better if we have it), and authenticate that user against the university's Azure AD and then send a token back to the RN app. When RN app hits the `/getStudentData` endpoint, it will validate the token and fetch the student's data from the database.

I couldn't find the exact docs or tutorial I was looking for. Does anyone have any experience with something like this? I need to protect my API routes with MSAL but also have the ability to signin user with email and pwd. Is this a good architecture? Any recommendations for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: If you want to use email and password to login or authenticate the user, you can make use of
> **`acquireTokenByUsernamePassword`** method.

- But **`acquireTokenByUsernamePassword`** is not recommended by Microsoft for security reasons.
- Personal accounts or MFA enabled user accounts are not supported in ROPC flow.
- Hence, you can also make use of **`acquireTokenByCode()`** method to authenticate the user.

Create an **Azure AD application and grant API permissions** based on your requirement:

[image]

Generated **access token** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:password
scope:api://xxx/test.read
username:user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:***
client_id:ClientID
```

[image]

***To do the same in `msal-node`, use the below code:***

```js
const msal = require("@azure/msal-node");

const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "ClientID",
        authority: "Authority",
    }
};

const pca = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
const usernamePasswordRequest = {
    scopes: ["scope"],
    username: "username", 
    password: "***",
};

pca.acquireTokenByUsernamePassword(usernamePasswordRequest).then((response) => {
    console.log("acquired token by password grant");
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

**Otherwise** make use of **`acquireTokenByCode()`**  by referring this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-interactive?tabs=nodejs).

Comment: I think you helped me with exactly what I was looking for. But after reading, I realized that MFA accounts are not supported. I think this is a deal breaker (since the university requires people use this). So, let me ask you this: what would your suggestion be for my scenario: react native mobile app, with a nodejs server that queries the db (Azure AD is a must)? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If MFA is enabled you can make use of `acquireTokenByCode()` method